Power Automate - HTTP Request - Unknown image format
I'm trying to convert a .png file to .zpl using a public API and following this documentation (https://labelary.com/service.html) - point 6.1.
When I try it in Postman, it works very well.
Prints (PostMan)
https://prnt.sc/yBh7oJvy6YNG
https://prnt.sc/dR5F_q3J4qFV
I'm currently attempting the same process in Power Automate, but I'm encountering an error: 'ERROR: Unknown image format'.
Could someone help me troubleshoot? Here's my Power Automate setup:
https://prnt.sc/gOdzv8UAP3Pk
123.png is my image file, and varContent contains the content of 123.png in base64 format.
I'm doing something wrong?

Are you using the new designer in Power Automate? If so, try editing the flow in the old designer. The new designer still has some bugs when it comes to file content. You may need to edit all the parmeters where you access the file content, delete the reference to the file content and re-add it. Save in the old designer and test.

If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Thanks for the answer.
I'm not using the new designer.
I turned it off.
https://prnt.sc/ZwuQujEsJsYT
The problem seems to be different. Could it be that in the body the API does not expect the base64 of the image but something else?
